# Authotkey break loop on specific keypress

Tags: autohotkey

I am looking for a way to break this loop when I press any of the keys listed in that line. I know it doesn't work but I was hoping for an easy solution. Any help please?

```
NumpadDiv::
loop
    {
    sleep 1000
    ImageSearch, LineX, LineY, 2800, 1270, 2965, 1435, *200 Faster.png
    if ErrorLevel = 1
        {
        ImageSearch, LineX, LineY, 2800, 1270, 2965, 1435, *200 Slower.png
        if ErrorLevel = 1
            {
            Send, {Space}
            }
        }
    KeyPressed := (["Esc", "NumpadAdd", "NumpadSub", "NumpadMult"])
    break
    }
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GetKeyState()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm).

```
NumpadDiv::
loop
{
    sleep 1000
    ImageSearch, LineX, LineY, 2800, 1270, 2965, 1435, *200 Faster.png
    if ErrorLevel = 1
    {
        ImageSearch, LineX, LineY, 2800, 1270, 2965, 1435, *200 Slower.png
        if ErrorLevel = 1
            {
            Send, {Space}
            }
    }

    if (GetKeyState("Esc")
    || GetKeyState("NumpadAdd")
    || GetKeyState("NumpadSub")
    || GetKeyState("NumpadMult")) {
        break
    }
}
Return
```

Comment: That's for your simple solution. Note that one of those keys must be pressed down by the time the `if` statement is evaluated. Otherwise you can set a flag (something like setting a BREAK_LOOP variable to 1) with hotkeys.